# Community user's network profile displays top questions

Tags: bug, community-user, network-profile

On the [network profile for the Community user](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), it has two posts listed under Top Questions.

[image: Community user's top questions. (And a freehand red oval)]

On their respective question pages, the [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135317/make-first-letter-of-a-string-upper-case-with-maximum-performance) is attributed to "anon" while the [Workplace question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/57500/told-ive-been-asking-too-many-questions-and-put-on-review) is attributed to Community

[image: Stack Overflow question author]  [image: Workplace question author]

Comment: OMG, it finally happened.