# Odd things going on with Community ♦'s network profile

Tags: support, community-user, network-profile

The [network profile of the Community ♦ user](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) seems ... odd.

1. The [Top tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=top) contains these three questions. Why only those? Community ♦ owns many more questions (and answers) with a positive score.

   - [Make first letter of a string upper case (with maximum performance)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4135317/4751173) (a question posted by 'anon')
   - [How can I deal with being told I ask too many questions?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/57500/33983) (here, Community ♦ is actually shown as the owner)
   - [SharePoint 2010 books to prepare - dev focus](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/2/60926) (a CW question posted by 'anon')

   [image]
2. The [Activity tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity) runs into an error: https://stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/-1/community
3. The [Favorites tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=favorites) shows ±20 questions with a heavy bias towards Sharepoint Stack Exchange.

[image]

4. The [Accounts](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=accounts) tab only shows Area 51, even though the community user exists on all sites. What is even weirder is the view on the iOS app, which shows **105** sites. The entire network consists of about 170 sites, and most large sites seem to be present in the list. [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com) is one of the sites which is missing.

[image]

Has an ordinary user accidentally been merged with Community ♦ instead of deleted?

Comment: [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243539/295232) is similar, but it's three years old and the symptoms are slightly different this time.

Comment: Re favourites: [What can cause the Community user to have favorite questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175992/307988)

Comment: Also top posts: [Community user's network profile displays top questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295008/307988)

Comment: As for the app, the reason is most likely the API which returns the "real" info, while the site got some special code to hide certain things for non-real users. (Currently only Community, but in theory they can add more users with negative ID like they do already in chat, e.g. Feeds, Chicken, etc)